# Predator Helios 300 keyboard keys working intermittently

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop

My e, h, 7, 8 and u keys stop working individually but if I press the letter then another down (ie I press e and if it doesn't type, hold it down and press h and it types e), or hold 2 or 3 in that group down at the same time first, it works. Would replacing the keyboard fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have split something on the keyboard such as coffee or fizzy or juice then it would be possible to clean the keyboard, which might fix it.

Otherwise, I would try the keyboard in safe mode first.

- If it works then its one of your drivers
- If it does not then you need to replace the keyboard